# What happens to magical properties and spells on arrows when using arrowsplit or a splitting bow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

The arrowsplit spell from Champions of Ruin has a **masterwork** arrow as target and it creates 1d4+1 identical **masterwork** arrows. We all know that magical arrows are also masterwork arrows so they are a valid target for the spell.

Due to this I'm having some doubts on how to interpret the spell since it doesn't say what happens to magical properties of the arrow (or magical properties coming from the bow) because, unlike the splitting weapon property, it doesn't say wheter the arrows keep the magical properties once they are split.

Neither the splitting property nor the arrowsplit spell say what happens to spells cast on the arrow (say, for example, using the metamagic feat "Smiting Spell", or an arrow with "flame arrow" cast on it)

So, my questions are:

1. What happens to magical properties on the new arrows created when casting arrowsplit?
2. What happens to magical properties coming from the bow?
3. What happens to spells cast on arrows on which you use arrowsplit? 
   Is it lost? Only one arrow keeps it? All the arrows copy it? Something else?
4. Same as 3 but with splitting weapon property
5. This leads me to the ultimate question that sums almost all of them up: How many arrows do I get if I cast arrowsplit on a arrow and then use it with a splitting bow? 2, 1d4+2, 1d4+1, 2d4+2, something else...?
6. (A doubt I got while writing this question…) Does the arrosplit spell give me an extra 1d4+1 arrows other than the original one (bringing it to a total of 1d4+2) or is it just 1d4+1 and the original is lost?

Comment: I suggest putting your suggested answer _as an answer,_ personally. That allows people to vote on it, so you can see if you are correct, and if so, it can be accepted rather than an extra answer saying “you’re right.” (This is not necessary or anything if you don’t want to, there are some advantages to having it part of the question too.)

Comment: right, i didn't actually think about posting it as an answer, thanks

Comment: Should answers avoid rejecting this reading entirely and, instead, reading *identical* as modifying the *created* arrows rather than the *targeted* arrow?

Comment: I'm ok with any answer as long as it has a good explaination (possibly with quotes from the rules where available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently these are my answers on the matter, but i'm not sure they are right:

1. (1 and 2) All the magical properties are kept when using arrowsplit (even though the spell says it splits into masterwork arrows, it also says they are identical to the original)
2. (3 and 4) Only one arrow keeps a spell cast on it when it's split (it doesn't say, but we can assume one is the original arrow and the others are just copies)
3. (5) Therefore, an arrow with arrowsplit thrown from a splitting bow splits into 1d4+2 arrows (or +3 depending on the answer to 6)
4. (6) I think it's just 1d4+1, but i'm not really sure on this

Comment: Since a splitting bow uses *arrowsplit* as it's base, that be considered a same-source issue.

Comment: yes i was considering that

Answer (score 0):

### They go away.

Reading strictly, the arrowsplit spell says only that the arrow "split[s]...into...identical masterwork arrows." I.e. it becomes multiple arrows, and those arrows each are identical and have the masterwork quality. It dies not say that it splits them into identical masterwork arrows "with the same effects as the original" or anything similar. It doesn't even say that the original arrow is one of the product arrows

As you have identified, you could indeed use magic arrows to cast this spell. When you do so, they are consumed (like all other material components) and you get regular masterwork arrows as a product.

So:

1. There are none.
2. Each projectile still would have been launched by the bow, so would inherit the bow effects (I think. Even that is arguable).
3. Spells *actually on the arrows* would be gone, as with (1). Spells like *true strike* do not target the arrow and would presumably apply to all of the attack rolls associated with that attack.
4. Not clear what you're asking. Splitting weapon on the bow or the arrows? And do you mean to say same as (2)?
5. Not well defined. Based on my answer to (2), I would say you probably get 2x(1d4+1) arrows.
6. Spells do exactly what they say. *Arrowsplit* says "split in mid-flight into 1d4+1 identical masterwork arrows." That means 1 arrow turns into 1d4+1 arrows. It does not add 1d4+1 arrows.